# Need a solution for distribute files

Tags: .net, asp.net, file-io, distribute

I have a file manager application that is writed by asp.net MVC. User can upload, delete, rename and ... any file by it. I deploy this program on D partition and now It is full and I added a new hard disk. I want to write the new file uploaded on the new hard disk (E partition). now some files are on D: and some files are on E: .
I want to distribute the files in different partitions.
Is there any solution to manage all files without doing any change in the code of my program.
Please don't offer hard merging.
I think it is possible by link one folder to multi folder.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming this is Windows, the operating system can do this itself; instead of mounting the disk as E:, create an empty folder somewhere on D: and mount the new drive *there*. This is available on most operating systems, via different routes.

Start => right-click Computer => Manage => Storage => Disk Management

find the drive, right-click, Change Drive Letter and Paths..., Add..., Mount in the following empty NTFS folder

Comment: Is it possible to mount multi hard disk to one folder? if yes: when I write a file on that folder the file actullay write on witch hard disk?

Comment: @Ghooti - the mount-point must be an empty folder, however, you could have multiple sub-folders each of which is a different physical disk.